# How to setup persistance with Network of Brokers in ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic, leveldb, kahadb

Is it possible to use KahaDB based persistance with network of brokers in ActiveMQ. I need to setup network of broker to mitigate risk of single point of failure with single centralized broker (master/slave).

Answer (score 0):

If you do mean "network of brokers", yes, you just need to config KahaDb for each brokers, no difference with single point.

But network of brokers is different with master/slave, it is used to allow many brokers to be connected together, to provide massive scalability.

If you mean master/slave, it does not support kahadb yet, but is under review, see http://activemq.apache.org/kahadb-master-slave.html